# react hook state does not update

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am around a project in react and trying to call a hook inside a function but it is not updating!

the code in question is this

```
function ProductSingle(products){

    const [product,setProduct] = useState(products.location.state.products)
    console.log(product)
    const [antal, setAntal] = useState(0)

    const dispatch = useDispatch()


    const artikelg = useSelector(state => state.products)
    const colorGroup = Object.values(artikelg)
    .filter(color => color.Artikelgrupp === product.Artikelgrupp)

    const colors = colorGroup.map((color) =>{
        console.log(color)
        return (
            <>
                <Cor a1={color.färg} a2={color.färg} a3={color.färg} onClick={color => setProduct(color)} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}/>
            </>
        )}
    )
```

however setProduct does not update for the mapped object. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you call `ProductSingle`? A functional component accepts an object as first and only parameter. That object has a property called according to which property you pass. In your example I would first correct `function ProductSingle(products){` to `function ProductSingle({products}){`

Comment: try this  onClick={()=> setProduct(color)}

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. This code is incomplete to an extend that makes it very hard to understand what its supposed to do. What does the component render? Why is a state called `product` initialized with what seems to be a list of products? What does this component receive as props and why are they named `products`? What does the `Cor` component pass to the onClick handler? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The efforts people put into an answer is proportional to the effords you put into your question.

Answer (score 0):

try to use just `onClick={() => setProduct(color)}`

You can't really do this `onClick={color => setProduct(color)}` because `onClick` takes event.